# TypeError: css() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, scrapy, typeerror, scrapy-splash

Receiving the following error, TypeError: css() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given), when trying to run the following web scraping program.  I need the program to scrape these card names from the following website, http://www.starcitygames.com/catalog/category/Duel%20Decks%20Venser%20vs%20Koth and the problem is in order to scrape all the content I need I have to have two variables in the loop. But I do not know if I even set the loop up right for it to work simultaneously for it to look for both strings in the HTML code.

SplashSpider.py

```
import csv
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from ..items import GameItem

# process the csv file so the url + ip address + useragent pairs are the same as defined in the file # returns a list of dictionaries, example:
# [ {'url': 'http://www.starcitygames.com/catalog/category/Rivals%20of%20Ixalan',
#    'ip': 'http://204.152.114.244:8050',
#    'ua': "Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9320; en-GB) AppleWebKit/534.11"},
#    ...
# ]
def process_csv(csv_file):
    data = []
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader)
    for fields in reader:
        if fields[0] != "":
            url = fields[0]
        else:
            continue # skip the whole row if the url column is empty
        if fields[1] != "":
            ip = "http://" + fields[1] + ":8050" # adding http and port because this is the needed scheme
        if fields[2] != "":
            useragent = fields[2]
        data.append({"url": url, "ip": ip, "ua": useragent})
    return data


class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'splash_spider'  # Name of Spider

    # notice that we don't need to define start_urls
    # just make sure to get all the urls you want to scrape inside start_requests function

    # getting all the url + ip address + useragent pairs then request them
    def start_requests(self):

        # get the file path of the csv file that contains the pairs from the settings.py
        with open(self.settings["PROXY_CSV_FILE"], mode="r") as csv_file:
           # requests is a list of dictionaries like this -> {url: str, ua: str, ip: str}
            requests = process_csv(csv_file)

        for req in requests:
            # no need to create custom middlewares
            # just pass useragent using the headers param, and pass proxy using the meta param

            yield SplashRequest(url=req["url"], callback=self.parse, args={"wait": 3},
                    headers={"User-Agent": req["ua"]},
                    splash_url = req["ip"],
                    )

    # Scraping
    def parse(self, response):
        item = GameItem()
        for game1,game2 in response.css("tr.deckdbbody_row","tr.deckdbbody2_row"):
            # Card Name
            item["card_name"] = game_1.css("a.card_popup::text").extract_first()
            item["card_name"] = game_2.css("a.card_popup::text").extract_first()
```

Error message

```
2019-06-04 10:36:39 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.starcitygames.com/catalog/category/Duel%20Decks%20Venser%20vs%20Koth via http://204.152.114.229:8050/render.html> (referer: None) Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/trno224/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/trno224/scrapy_splash/scrapy_javascript/scrapy_javascript/spiders/SplashSpider.py", line 56, in parse
    for game1,game2 in response.css("tr.deckdbbody_row","tr.deckdbbody2_row"):
TypeError: css() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
2019-06-04 10:36:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-06-04 10:36:39 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1149,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 131347,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 4, 14, 36, 39, 136675),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 55750656,
 'memusage/startup': 54394880,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'spider_exceptions/TypeError': 1,
 'splash/render.html/request_count': 1,
 'splash/render.html/response_count/200': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 4, 14, 35, 28, 761764)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this CSS expression (similar to `starts-with()`):

```
for game in response.css("tr[class^=deckdbbody]"):
    # Card Name
    item["card_name"] = game.css("a.card_popup::text").extract_first()
```

Answer (score -1):

you can get your two variable with zip :

```html
for game1,game2 in zip(response.css("tr.deckdbbody_row"), response.css("tr.deckdbbody2_row"):
    # Card Name
    item["card_name"] = game_1.css("a.card_popup::text").extract_first()
    item["card_name"] = game_2.css("a.card_popup::text").extract_first()
```